# I can't fix an annoying error in my script

Tags: python, while-loop

I am making a Rock, Paper, Scissors game for my school project and it was finished but it suddenly stopped working. I think it is a problem in the `while` loop.

```
while UserHand or UserHand_Retry != "Rock" and UserHand or UserHand_Retry != "Paper" and UserHand or UserHand_Retry != "Scissors":
    tkMessageBox.showerror("ERROR!","You did not choose a valid object, please try again.")
    UserHand_Retry = raw_input("What do you want to choose? (Rock/Paper/Scissors):")
```

Comment: *"it suddenly stopped working"* is not helpful. What is not working? Is it throwing an error message? Is it producing incorrect results?

Comment: define "it suddenly stopped working".  Is it throwing an error or what?

Comment: A program like this doesn't just randomly stop working - more likely, *you changed something that broke it*. Change it back!

Comment: `UserHand or UserHand_Retry == "Rock"` does not do what you think it does. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values

Comment: Also consider taking this over to code review once it is working.  There's a lot of clutter that could be cleaned up.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear enough, but no matter what I do, if I use Rock, Paper or Scissors it gives the error message again and again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `while` condition will be `True` if `UserHand` is any non-empty value, like `'a'`, or `'3333'`, because of

```
UserHand or UserHand_Retry....
```

since `or` needs only one of these to be `True` and `UserHand` will be evaluated as `True` if it's a non-empty string.

```
while UserHand not in ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]:
```

Also, be careful with multiple `or` and `and` in your condition; that might work differently than you expected. Use `(` and `)` if you're unsure.

Comment: It would be helpful to add *at the very least* where this line should go, and much better if you explained why it's better than what it's replacing.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, The code is self explanatory for any programmer with even a smidgen of common sense.  ++.  In fact, most answers require no explanation.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: There is only one place with while.
You're right about explanation, I guess

Comment: Added explanation, thank you for comments

Comment: @jonrsharpe, thank your for style fixes, didn't know I can do that inline

Comment: I will try to use this list tomorrow and thanks everyone for helping me, starting on this website!